# jQuery - scrollTop not working as expected

Tags: jquery, scrolltop

**CODE:**

```
if(jQuery("#content h1.title").length > 0){
    jQuery('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: jQuery("#content h1.title:first").offset().top - jQuery("#sticky").outerHeight()
    }, 2000);
}
```

**PROBLEM:**
The code above works fine if im already on page and then hit the refresh button. Otherwise, if I manually open page in browser, the code above ll scroll bellow H1.
Div #sticky has position fixed and its height is 60px. Why is this happening and how to solve it?

I have tried to put code above into the $(window).load(), results are the same.
offset().top return different values on refresh even if it located inside $(window).load().

Comment: FYI you can just check if(jQuery("#content h1.title").length )

Comment: In that case, if always return true, at least in my case..

Comment: Works code: http://jsfiddle.net/9rqne/

Comment: Thanks, but this is not what i need :)